# Getting 0xC000041D crash in simple directX12 application

Tags: crash, unhandled-exception, directx-12

I have a simple Window class and I use a function for WM_PAINT that clears the render target view and presents the final image.so there's not much into it but I get a crash on line `FLOAT clearColor[] = { 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 1.0f };` that says:0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.
here's the window class:

```
class Win32Window : public WindowsWindow
{
public:
    Win32Window(const WindowProps& props);
    virtual ~Win32Window();
    void OnUpdate() override;
    unsigned int GetWidth() const override { return m_Data.Width; }
    unsigned int GetHeight() const override { return m_Data.Height; }
    void SetEventCallback(const EventCallbackFn& callback) override { m_Data.EventCallback = callback; }
    void SetVSync(bool enabled) override;
    bool IsVSync() const override;
    virtual void* GetNativeWindow() const override { return m_Window; }
private:
    HWND m_Window;
    RECT m_WindowRect;
    HINSTANCE m_hInst;
    LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void Init(const WindowProps& props);
    virtual void Shutdown();
};
```

the definitions:

```
Win32Window::Win32Window(const WindowProps& props)
{
    HZ_PROFILE_FUNCTION();
    Init(props);
}
Win32Window::~Win32Window()
{
    HZ_PROFILE_FUNCTION();
    Shutdown();
}
void Win32Window::Init(const WindowProps& props)
{
    m_hInst = GetModuleHandle(0);
    m_Data.WideCharacterTitle = props.WideCharacterTitle;
    m_Data.Width = props.Width;
    m_Data.Height = props.Height;
    HZ_CORE_INFO("Creating window {0} ({1}, {2})",props.StringTypeTitle, props.Width, props.Height);

    WNDCLASSEXW windowClass = {};
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = m_hInst;
    windowClass.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(m_hInst, NULL);
    windowClass.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = m_Data.WideCharacterTitle;
    windowClass.hIconSm = ::LoadIcon(m_hInst, NULL);
    static ATOM atom = ::RegisterClassExW(&windowClass);
    assert(atom > 0);

    int screenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    RECT windowRect = { 0, 0, static_cast<LONG>(m_Data.Width), static_cast<LONG>(m_Data.Height) };
    ::AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
    int windowWidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    int windowHeight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
    int windowX = std::max<int>(0, (screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2);
    int windowY = std::max<int>(0, (screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2);
    m_Window = ::CreateWindowExW(NULL, m_Data.WideCharacterTitle, m_Data.WideCharacterTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hInst, this);
    assert(m_Window && "Failed to create window");
    m_Context = GraphicsContext::Create(m_Window);
    m_Context->Init();
    ::ShowWindow(m_Window, SW_SHOW);
    ::UpdateWindow(m_Window);
}
LRESULT Win32Window::MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
       m_Context->RenderWindow();
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
LRESULT Win32Window::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Win32Window* instance;
    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        instance = (Win32Window*)(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        instance->m_Window = hwnd;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)instance);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = (Win32Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }
    if (instance) 
    {
        return instance->MainWndProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
void Win32Window::Shutdown()
{
    DestroyWindow(m_Window);
    m_Window = nullptr;
}
void Win32Window::OnUpdate()
{
    m_Context->Update();
}
void Win32Window::SetVSync(bool enabled)
{
    m_Data.VSync = enabled;
}
bool Win32Window::IsVSync() const
{
    return m_Data.VSync;
}
```

m_Context is coming from the parent class, And also WindowProps that has some data for initializing the window .definition of m_Context->RenderWindow():

```
m_CommnadQueue = D3D12Core::Get().GetCommandQueue(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT);
    auto m_CommandList = m_CommnadQueue->GetCommandList();
    m_CurrentBackBufferIndex = m_SwapChain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();
    auto m_BackBuffer = D3D12Core::Get().m_BackBuffers[m_CurrentBackBufferIndex];
    auto m_RTVDescriptorSize = D3D12Core::Get().GetDevice()->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
    {
        CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_BackBuffer.Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET);
        m_CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
        FLOAT clearColor[] = { 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtv(m_RTVDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), m_CurrentBackBufferIndex, m_RTVDescriptorSize);
        m_CommandList->ClearRenderTargetView(rtv, clearColor, 0, nullptr);
    }
    {
        CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_BackBuffer.Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT);
        m_CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
        m_CommandList->Close();
        ID3D12CommandList* const commandLists[] =
        {
            m_CommandList.Get()
        };
        D3D12Core::Get().m_FenceValues[m_CurrentBackBufferIndex] = m_CommnadQueue->ExecuteCommandList(m_CommandList);
        UINT syncInterval = m_VSync;
        UINT presentFlags = m_TearingSupport && !m_VSync ? DXGI_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING : 0;
        m_SwapChain->Present(syncInterval, presentFlags);
        m_CommnadQueue->WaitForFenceValue(D3D12Core::Get().m_FenceValues[m_CurrentBackBufferIndex]);
    }
```

If there is anything else that I should put in question pls tell me.You can shout at me for my dumbness if you want to but help me pls,thx.
EDIT:
debug layer:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
        ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugInterface;
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugInterface))))
        {
            debugInterface->EnableDebugLayer();
        }
#endif
```

Comment: On your previous question, I was suspicious that Debug Layer didn't caught your heap initialization bug so I tested it and the debug layer actually shows an error. My point is make sure your debug layer is really working. If you have #ifdef _DEBUG around your debug layer than make sure you are running in debug mode. On to your question here, despite the crash showing on the line clearColor, it's probably the line above with resource barrier. My first guess would be that maybe you didn't reset your command list before recording? But make sure that debug layer is enabled and working properly.

Comment: I also don't see calls to OMSetRenderTargets, maybe it would be better if you added code with graphics stuff (you can probably remove window class, I doubt there is problem with it). And maybe consider not using WM_PAINT for rendering https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/wm-paint-and-direct3d

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will stop using WM_PAINT after I solved this crash. First I placed the Debug Layer into somewhere wrong. now I placed it where it gets called properly and now the crash is gone but I get a white screen without any errors from debug layer. I tested these codes as it was in the tutorial and it worked fine but now when I try to use them inside an engine, I always get a white screen. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the codes themselves so I'm confused what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Now I moved debug layer to a more reasonable place than before and now I get the same crash again. I have a commandqueue class that returns the commandlist and before it returns it, resets it.

Comment: Just to check, can you reproduce your error with descriptor heap from your last question and ensure that debug layer outputs message as it should ? I am guessing you know where message gets outputed. It's hard to play guessing game like this so I would like to sure you enabled it right.  You should also post your code regarding debug layer in your post.

Comment: It's embarrassing but maybe you guessed right and I really don't know where message gets output. I thought it gets output in the console command and now I know I was wrong. Can you tell me where? I don't know why I was ignoring the debug layer in this whole time. I will put the debug layer in my question.

Comment: It doesn't get outputed to console, it gets output in microsoft visual studio output window https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019 . If you don't see it, go to View->Output.

Comment: I had output enabled but I ignored the debug layer errors. I don't know why ._. . Even a monkey has higher IQ than me. you were right. It's resource barrier that causes the crash. The error it shows is this: `D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ResourceBarrier: NULL pointer specified. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #520: RESOURCE_BARRIER_NULL_POINTER]`

Comment: No need to go hard on yourself, you learn something everyday. It seems your m_BackBuffer is nullptr and in previous question you initialized it in UpdateRenderTargetViews. Did you change something in your code, are you calling UpdateRenderTargetViews ? You can always debug it line by line and find the cause.

Comment: You were right . I fixed that . I'm sorry for this but there in another error: `D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandQueue::ExecuteCommandLists: Using Draw on Command List'Unnamed ID3D12GraphicsCommandList Object': Resource state (0x0: D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_[COMMON|PRESENT]) of resource 'Unnamed ID3D12Resource Object' is invalid for use as a render targe` on the last line of RenderWindow().

Comment: Again, I am playing guessing game here, but maybe you are not setting your render targets every frame, ie, I don't see a call like this: _command_list->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtv_handle, FALSE, nullptr);

Comment: zezanjee I don't how to thank you.It's working now. I was stuck with this and couldn't get out of it. but I didn't know about OMSetRenderTargets. What it actually does?

Comment: One other thing. It's may be a guessing again but do you know the possible reasons that why the window freezes and does not respond?

Comment: That is DirectX way of telling which render target you want to render to. For more detailed explanation see learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/. I cannot even guess what could be the reason for window freeze, lots of things could be a cause.

Comment: OK. Thx a lot. You helped me so mush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WaitForFenceValue` after every `Present` is an extremely slow way to render in DirectX 12. You should generally cue 2-3 frames to the GPU rather than forcing the GPU to stall every frame. It is also highly problematic to have your `WndProc` block, which is what happens here. Your `WndProc` should always complete quickly as many hundreds of messages are processed a second for most applications.

Usually Direct3D rendering is not done within `WM_PAINT`. For a number of examples of common render loops, see [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).